# 419 Error when POST'ing to Laravel Passport route to create client

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

I've added support for [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) to my project and I'm trying to test creating a client by using their JSON API.  I've gone through the steps to add Passport many times and can confirm I've added Passport according to their steps.  [Here is a link to the branch of my code that implements Passport](https://github.com/dbudwin/RoboHome-Web/tree/Save).  My request looks like the following:

```
POST /oauth/clients HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost:8000
accept: application/json
content-length: 67

{
  "name": "MyTestClient",
  "redirect": "https://www.google.com"
}
```

And the response I get is:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 203,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 59,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 647,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 622,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 588,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 577,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/me/Documents/code/RoboHome-Web-Port/RoboHome-Web/server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you just need to **disable CSRF** protection on the  passport routes.

CSRF is used to make sure an internal requests is actually internal. In your case they specifically are not, so you don't need it. You will be securing these routes with OAuth (passport) instead.